# C# MVC4 ActionResult ActionFilter for FormCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, attributes, overriding, action-filter

I have the following ActionResults and one is meant to be an override of the other that accepts a FormCollection as a parameter.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PartialAverageDisplay()
    {
        HomeModel C = new HomeModel();
        ChViewModel D = new ChViewModel();
        D = C.AverageCalculation();

        return PartialView(D);
    }
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PartialAverageDisplay(FormCollection myFcollection)
    {
         HomeModel C = new HomeModel();
         System.Data.DataTable myDT = new System.Data.DataTable();
         myDT = (DataTable)Session["DT"];
         ChViewModel D = new ChViewModel();
         D = C.AverageCalculation(myDT, myFcollection);

            return PartialView(D);
        }
```

I've been unable to find an example online of how to create an actionfilter attribute for requiring a FormCollection.  Everything Ive seen has used an array of strings.  Im not experienced with creating actionfilters.  Can anyone explain to me how to approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MVC does not allow you to have overrides of the same method with the same Action verb (Post, get, etc..).  You can only have one HttpPost per method name.  It will compile, but you will get an Ambiguous call error at runtime.

This also includes having multiple ActionName's to try to get around the problem.  The problem is that the URL can only map to a single action of that type.

Comment: The actionresult returns a partialview containing a populated datatable.  On the main view page this datatable should load the first time with hard-coded values.  When checkboxes contained in my Form Collection are clicked a jquery function should post to the other actionresult in order to re-render the partialview and populate the datatable with different results.  What other ways can I achieve this?

Comment: @HendPro12 - Why don't you just change the name?